# Question tags appear on top of error message in the Z order

Tags: bug, design, error-message

I recently stumbled upon a question that I had downvoted because [I hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). In a brief moment of weakness, I tried to undo my downvote, only to learn that it had been locked in. All good, except…

Another Z order bug! The question's tag (only a single one, [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), appropriately) appeared on top of the system's error message:

[image]

Obviously, the error message should be the highest item in the Z order so that it appears atop everything else.

I suspect it may also be a bug that the error message is horizontally compressed to this extent, as it makes it very difficult to read.
**Update:** Yup, this is definitely a bug. All system pop-up messages are horizontally compressed like this, including the "You have *x* votes left today" message.

Comment: So *you* are the anonymous down voter ....

Comment: Well, at least it's an appropriate tag for what's happening...

Comment: +1 for red freehand circle. -1 for low contrast because the background is also red.

Comment: I think the freehand circle should have been dark blue.

Comment: The error create a nice message: *"Your vote is `bug`..."*