# What is SE's (the company) mission statement for their websites, and in particular SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I was recently told by a user that [management and the contributing core differ in goals for SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377101/can-we-be-more-welcoming-by-managing-expectations/377127#comment651146_377127). I already believed this to some extent, but it is all just gut feeling. I have been around for a couple years, and I think my understanding of core user base's goal is correct:

> Create a repository of high quality questions and answers

The first go to read for any programmer stuck on anything (programming related...).

Following the recent Twitter debacle (disgrace?), I found a honest post by [Jon Ericson](https://jericson.github.io/2018/10/24/lost_trust.html), with some key sentences that struck me:

> For my part, I’ve sensed an erosion of community capital for several
>   years and it’s no longer a resource we can reliably draw from.

and

> Our collaboration with users in developing the Q&A engine was very
>   nearly unique. It’s tragic that we are in the process of losing that
>   unusual relationship if the damage hasn’t been done entirely.

and

> My analysis is that we as an organization have taken on an unhealthy
>   role with the developer community and our users. I won’t go into
>   detail here, but the company pursued its goals with the assumption
>   that our users would be eager to participate. And it turns out that’s
>   only really true when our goals directly help users reach their goal
>   to build a library of answers to questions on whatever topic inspires
>   them.

By all means read the entire post, I definitely recommend it. I am not sure the "optimistic" part will read that way to everyone. This was also previously expressed by [Nick Larsen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366757/on-the-false-dichotomy-between-quality-and-kindness/366783#comment579888_366783) (there is an answer and a fiery conversation but I think this is most succinct:

> "we are here to create an artifact that will help the next person who
>   has that question" is a fundamental flaw of the description of the
>   site, that should be a side effect, not the goal.

Anyway - this feels like SE is heading in another direction, disconnecting from the user-base and deciding to become more focused and goal driven. But the question remains - what is the bottom line? **What is the single sentence description SE envisions for SO? The mission statement?**

and another great and highly relevant point by Don't Panic, **What does SE consider its user base?**, and if there are several "classes", **How is each user type expected to interact with SO?**

Perhaps this will help alleviate some of the tensions recently on meta(s) if it is expressed.

**Clarification**

I'm looking for a one line answer which is the mission statement. Ideally from someone at SE , after internal discussion if need be. The answer can continue on with an elaboration, but I feel a mission statement is something that will help guide us, or at least help us understand corporate state of mind.

We all want to make money,  and that's not a bad thing. It does not us define though (in my opinion) .

Comment: Maybe part of the reason for the tensions on meta is that SE and meta have a different idea of what the user base is.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Oo I like that - I am leeching it into the question if you do not mind.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Let me know if the wording suits you, since I use your name.

Comment: It's fine, no worries. You don't really have to reference me. I was just reminded of a thought I've had for a while when I saw you mention user base. (And I feel like I should state that I didn't bring it up to suggest anything negative. I really am curious if there is a difference of opinion there.)

Comment: Personally, I don't think it'll alleviate tensions; SE's undergone a shift in recent years towards a more user-focused experience, over the previous quality-focused one most users still adhere to.  It can be seen in [Nick's dismissal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366783/), and the total lack of progress of feature improvements to the [core curation process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314348/).  Making that disconnect plain, however, will cause many on the fence to nope out of continuing *any* curation, which is detrimental to further efforts.

Comment: @Don'tPanic This whole question is just a curiosity thing.

Comment: @kabanus That comment read better when you ignore the `@` at the start of it.

Comment: My gut feeling is that there is money to be made because they have thousands of programmers on this site who help answer questions daily, so they essentially have an extremely successful site supported entirely by people who do the things that make it successful for free. For ad-revenue or whatever other business interests, goals like increasing the userbase and page views are much easier to fulfill by turning Stack Overflow into a friendly help desk that tolerates low quality questions, and they think Stack Overflow is too big to fail (meaning, the programmers won't leave) if they do that.

Comment: Note my comment is with regards to my feelings, not with regards to any facts I have on hand.

Comment: @DavyM but those are not a statement of purpose for a serious company. They need some some catch phrase bottom line, like "Google will find you anything on the internet" or the like.

Comment: @DavyM found Google's actual one : *“to organize the world’s information and make it universally accessible and useful.”*.

Comment: @DavyM "goals like increasing the userbase and page views are much easier to fulfill by turning Stack Overflow into a friendly help desk that tolerates low quality questions" Well, the fact that SO became successful in a world full of sites like that suggests that the opposite is true, but you're correct that SO's actions and public statements imply that they believe that to be true, despite so much evidence to the contrary.

Comment: How the relationship between the company and its site users got so thoroughly destroyed is surely going to be the subject of a MBA case study some day.  This question was asked [over 4 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal).  Nothing changed.  Jon's stated "sub-goal" of "stabilize and grow" did not pan out well, SO shrank, lost its Google ranking in the fall of last year and they had to layoff a bunch of employees.  It's not like we didn't warn them about that :)

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the great historical reference! (and long read :) ) . Now I am interested what the current official mission statement - I hope SE has one and is willing to divulge it. Could be the eventual title of said MBA chapter. Note an answer should be considerably shorter than your old one.

Comment: TBH, I don't think SE is being *that* stupid here. The disconnect between SE and users isn't because SE decided one day, "Hey, let's piss off our userbase to see what happens!". I think the cause-and-effect is the other way around. SO - after being so successful for so many years has finally reached content saturation. And because of the hard "no-dupes" policies, inflow of new quality content has gone down to zero. Without any new content, it's hard to retain users. SE pissing on the veteran userbase to make the site "more friendly" is just a (potentially ill-advised) response to this.

Comment: _"content saturation"_ I'm dubious of this point. There are question subjects being invented all the time -- new platforms, frameworks, languages, etc. (And existing environments getting new features.) Just as one example, [tag:swift] was released *after* the post Hans linked and is a huge source of posts.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I only meant it relatively. When SO started, there were decades of technologies which hadn't been "cataloged" in SO. It took roughly 6 years of very successful SO to burn through all of that. With the fuel having run out, we're now running in real-time with respect to new technologies. While it's not zero, the flow of legitimate new content is only a small fraction of what it used to be.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: then a long term overview of questions would show a shift from "old" languages to these new ones. But I see the very same questions popping up every time a fresh class in C, C++, JavaScript, Java, or Python is started. I am sure a graph of closed-as-duplicate will show when regular semesters start.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, @Mysticial, and good point, \@usr.

Comment: I'm dubious as well.  Atwood got very worried when SO hit 2000 questions/day.  Hah, got a lot bigger than that, 10K/workday.  Question, smestion, interesting content is only ever provided by subject experts, they are spread thin and can't find each other's posts anymore.

Comment: @Mysticial Keep in mind that SO makes the *vast* majority of its money from users without accounts coming in from Google to get the answer to a question they have. They don't get much money (directly) from users asking questions, or posting answers.  Active users see very few, if any, ads.  Anonymous users are the ones generating the ad revenue.   So even if SO started getting quite a lot fewer new questions, as long as it's still the main reference source for programmers they're still making lots of money, probably more than when building that archive of questions.

Comment: So making changes that reduce quality, and make SO a poorer reference source, in exchange for a few more people asking (low quality) questions doesn't make sense from a purely monetary bottom line perspective.

Comment: @Servy Wouldn't be the first time investors have killed a golden goose to get at its eggs, and it certainly won't be the last. Capitalism without foresight kills everything in the end.

Comment: I believe the official mission statement by SO is "It is time to take a stand against Donald Trump". Not a joke.

Comment: @Lundin I remember that post. I give them enough credit to not repeat that mistake.

Comment: I am also beginning to worry there is no mission statement. I wish someone in the know would at least comment to let us know if this is something thought about.

Answer (score 21):

<sub>What follows is my [back-of-the-envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-of-the-envelope_calculation) interpretation as someone who has a formal education in business management and administration and who has been active on SO Main & Meta for several years (though far from the entire life of the site). I have no affiliation with Stack Overflow the company; I'm just a user (they've never even sent me such much as a tee-shirt or coffee mug).</sub>

As Hans has mentioned in the comments, this [has come up before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal). Last time the question was asked, some great answers to your specific questions in bold were provided or surmised. However, allow me to provide my own interpretation of the answer to your overarching question, along with an attempt at describing the conflict between Meta and the company.

### What's the bottom line goal of *insert company here*? Money.

The goal of Stack Overflow *the company* is to make money. That's the goal and [raison d'être](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raison_d%27%C3%AAtre) of any for-profit enterprise; when a company stops making money, it tends to goes away, either by folding or selling or getting [acqui-hired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acqui-hiring).

The driving reason for the *founders* to start the company in the first place, and the goal for Stack Overflow *the website*, is to create the world's most complete and highest-quality repository of programming knowledge (and with other SE sites, insert whichever subject-specific knowledge is appropriate), because they were fed up with the general lack of good destinations for programming questions—existing ones were either small/fragmented, behind paywalls, not designed well, etc.

In practical terms, you can understand the company's *stated* goal (this company or any company) purely as a function of making money. As previously stated, once you have a business, it needs revenue or it ceases to exist (OK, it doesn't magically disappear, but your employees will leave and your assets will get seized and liquidated to pay off creditors and shareholders if you cannot pay your debts). So what is Stack Overflow's market? Every company needs something to *be* and *do*. In Stack Overflow's case, they made a Q&A network where people can come and get quality answers to clear, concise questions they may have.

Luckily for them (and some may say lucky for the internet), Stack Overflow Q&A was a huge success; the focus on quality, on user moderation, on cutting out the noise and discussion that plagued other sites, and tying reputation to contributions was clearly a winning formula. By now, though, the Q&A software has largely matured and thus doesn't really change that drastically anymore. Most changes are adjustments or small bug fixes; Q&A rarely sees new features (much to Meta's chagrin). However, there's a business reason for this: Q&A doesn't make money.

### So what makes money?

Q&A is necessary, because it's what draws the *users* here, and any social network (which is partly what Stack Overflow is) needs a large user pool and steady growth to survive, and Q&A is the reason that Joel and Jeff kicked the whole thing off in the first place, but their business model has never been Q&A. In fact, one of the reasons they made Q&A the way they did is because of their distaste for other sites who monetized Q&A -- either by paying per answer/question or by putting the whole site behind a paywall. So, they'd need to find some way to bring in revenue.

### Enter Advertisements

I wasn't here at the beginning, so I don't know if it started out with ads or if they came along later, but ads were an initial source of revenue (not counting funds raised from angel investors/venture capitalists, e.g. "seed money"). However, for a site as big as Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange, ad revenue is not enough, especially when you consider how many people use ad blockers, and how Stack Overflow's own software shows progressively fewer ads to registered users as they continue using the site. Users can even choose to see fewer ads in some cases in the profile settings. While ads do provide a substantial revenue source, it's not enough for real growth of a web-based business, especially one the size of Stack Overflow.

### Bring on Jobs and Enterprise

So along come SO Jobs (née Careers) and Stack Overflow for Enterprise. Jobs, of course, is a job board like Monster.com where members of Stack Overflow can offer themselves for employment at programming-specific jobs tailored to particular criteria, and various companies pay for access to this incredibly valuable pool of talented/experienced programmers. Likewise, SO for Enterprise is a business offering that provides the Stack Overflow site architecture to other companies who have the need for it.

### Teams (take two)

Recently the company launched Stack Overflow for Teams as an enterprise/business offering (not to be confused with Stack Overflow Teams, which was offered as an internal SO user offering, but had little to no direction, and crashed and burned pretty quickly). I have not used Teams or Enterprise, but it seems to me that Teams largely cannibalizes the SO Enterprise market... the largest difference seems to be that Teams is basically "Private SO hosted in the cloud" whereas Enterprise is "Private SO hosted on premises".

### So... what's their priority?

Until sometime this year or last, you could go to Stack Overflow's company website and see the list of employees and get a sense of how invested the company was in these products by comparing the size of the employee teams... unfortunately at some point this page was apparently de-linked or removed and now you can only see a list of executives. Perhaps some digging on archive.org could produce a snapshot of the hundreds of employees SO had (and has) working on these products.

It's these products (and [more](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/)) that Stack Overflow focuses on in order to become/stay profitable and continue growing. Substantive changes to Q&A, as mentioned before, have more or less stopped coming. When they do, it's as a function of maintaining a healthy pool of users that has acceptable growth (see: making the site more new-user friendly or less hostile via "be nice" efforts and "new user on-boarding initiatives". These initiatives are great but they aren't targeted at *Q&A*; they're targeted at *continued user growth*. This is because...

### Stack Overflow is like Facebook.

When a social network is free, users aren't the customers; they're the product. Stack Overflow has made a largely successful business (so far) on the backs of its users, whether that is directly selling access to them (Ads, Jobs) or taking what they've learned with interacting and supporting developers needs (Enterprise, Teams software; Talent, Engagement services). Growth at Stack Overflow means more users. More users means more people to see and click on ads, more potential job applicants to entice recruiters and HR departments to SO Jobs, more data points for improving their Teams and Enterprise software, etc.

In short, Stack Overflow's focus and driving interest is in growing their capability to make more money off the fact that it has the biggest pool of programmers/software developers/tech-savvy users in the world. It's not focused on making the best repository of programming knowledge in the world anymore, because it thinks that it's already accomplished that (somewhat rightly so, IMHO).

---

### Okay, where does the Meta tension come from?

The Meta community is the user base largely involved with sustaining, and certainly involved with curating, the core foundation of Stack Overflow: Q&A. Unlike Stack Overflow's customers, we users come here almost exclusively for Q&A. We either need it, or we want to contribute to it in order to improve it (or both). Naturally, our interests for what the company does lie in improving what we use the most. We want to see new features for Q&A; we want to see bug fixes and feature requests handled rather than sitting idly by.

Meta users are very concerned about the focus on growth, because after a certain point, growth becomes harmful. Just like there is a sweet spot for any process, be it programming, cooking, factory assembly line production, etc., too many participants starts causing problems (see [too many cooks will spoil the broth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/too_many_cooks_spoil_the_broth)).

Some points of concern often raised on Meta are that there are too many people asking too many questions for content curators/subject-matter experts to keep up. This results in low-quality or repetitive questions (or in some cases, off-topic questions) sticking around and getting answers and drawing attention. This has a snowballing effect of reinforcing in some users' minds that that kind of content is OK and what Q&A is all about. So Meta asks for the company to stop focusing on user growth, and specifically to spend more time on improving its ability to handle/curate Q&A by adding tools to our toolbox and fixing site functions that are broken.

However, these users sometimes get *very* upset, because the fact is that Q&A just doesn't get changed or improved much these days. Without discussing whether Meta or the company is right or wrong regarding the direction Stack Overflow should head, I think the reason folks in the Meta community get so upset is that they fail to appreciate or understand the interests of Stack Overflow the company. It doesn't make money from Q&A *directly*, so it doesn't direct its resources to making Q&A users happier *directly*. There are businesses and organizations out there that are exceptions to this practice, but this practice is typically the rule: focus first on what makes us money, and as an addendum, spend left-over effort on the rest of the 'nice-to-have' stuff. Q&A *works*, despite the scores of [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s that don't also have [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) applied to them. It's clear that, right now, the company is doing the bare minimum (or close to it) at keeping the users placated and engaged without investing heavily in their original product.

This is sad and unfortunate for users, because high-quality Q&A is the original dream of the website's founders and what so many of us long for. But the reality is that the company has moved beyond building up Q&A, and on to efforts that directly bring in money. Barring a major shift in direction, SO is unlikely to return its focus to Q&A directly for some time. As a business, this is only natural. But most programmers are not businesspeople, they are programmers who view Stack Overflow as an incredibly useful and valuable toolbox that is getting less useful and less valuable to them over time as the toolbox becomes outdated and the tools inside become covered in rust (and not the type-safe kind, either). So it's understandable that users here are upset.

### Takeaway

My recommended takeaway from this is that users try to remain pragmatic. Understand that Stack Overflow is a business that is going to focus on its own interests and will likely place the concerns/desires of paying customers over the concerns/desires of its sentient product (users) in perpetuity. They may come and claim "the two are not mutually exclusive; we think we can provide a great product to both users and paying customers", and while that may be true, they don't have unlimited resources or bottomless pockets to make both happen. Given the choice between improving your revenue vs shoring up/dusting the cobwebs off of your foundation/fundamentals... most companies will choose improving revenue.

In the meantime, continue to post requests for new features, report bugs, etc. Slow progress is still progress, and as of yet there is not really a viable competitor or alternative to Stack Overflow, so users who leave SO are just... removed from the playing field. They probably still (and likely will always) read Q&A anonymously or under new accounts. If users *stay*, they get a (somewhat) inside track on shaping the course of Stack Overflow. Maybe CMs and Executives start listening/dropping by and taking user feedback more seriously. Maybe new executives come in and drive company culture back toward Q&A. And so on. If we're not here continuously recommending improvements because we got fed up and left, they may not know that there's a problem, or that there's room for improvement. And given a choice between an imperfect Stack Overflow that improves too slowly and no Stack Overflow, I will choose the imperfect Stack Overflow *every time*. I do not want to fall into the mental trap of [the perfect being the enemy of the good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_is_the_enemy_of_good).

<sub>(I have also heard non-SO Stack Exchange sites originally was touted as a paid enterprise before SE 2.0, but I haven't found anything concrete on that.)</sub>

Comment: "Stack Overflow is like Facebook" - you want me to buy some soap so we can wash that filth out of your mouth? :)

Comment: On a serious note, I see some things here which are common sense but I also feel like this gargantuan response is a knee-jerk overreaction to a fairly obvious truth.  What's worse is that this was spurred on by someone with all of 127 reputation to begin with.  Not as sold that person has seen as many hatless winters as we have.

Comment: @Makoto To be fair, I didn't click through to read the comment OP linked to until just now. It looks like that 127-rep user does have an ace up their sleeve though; they are citing a direct confirmation from company management that the Meta community is wrong. It'd be nice for them to be brave enough and come say how they actually feel, if that's the case, but I doubt we'll ever see that.

Comment: It reads like hearsay to me.  Not to put *too* fine a point on it, but it's the kind of deliberate phrasing that would fuel conspiracy theories.  Believe what you wanna though; nothing's actually *official* until an actual employee chimes in.  Who knows - that OP may be telling the truth all along.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks you for your interesting post! Very enlightening.

Comment: I don't buy this, a very large amount of feature requests would take very minimal effort (like creating new flag reasons and changing the descriptions on a few flags).  These are features that could be implemented by a single goddamn intern, Management at SO must be so astronomically incompetent they can't schedule even slow updates to the moderation user experience for the past 3 years.   Something else is going on and it really just doesn't make sense, its fine if the majority of focus is on monetary products, SO really doesn't need much change except from tools for moderators.

Comment: Thanks for the story comprehensive analysis. I realize though my question title is a bit misleading,  as this is not really an answer - I was looking for a mission statement,  but I realize "bottom line" is a misleading phrase here.

Comment: I'll edit a bit to clarify.

Comment: @opa: "These are features that could be implemented by a goddamn intern..." – please take a look at [`tag:bug`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) *every time* someone decides to change [the Theme](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321420/2564301), add a [sidebar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374683/2564301), or mess up the [z-order](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357918/2564301). This maintenance *is* clearly done by interns.

Comment: _"the fact that it has the biggest pool of programmers/software developers/tech-savvy users in the world"_ For the moment. And due to the fact that _"as of yet there is not really a viable competitor"_. But that field becomes more fertile with every contributor who _"got fed up and left"_. At some point someone is going to [make SO their arch-enemy](https://blog.codinghorror.com/whos-your-arch-enemy/)...and then where will the users that write the content that generates the revenue go?

Comment: Good writeup, though!

Comment: @opa:  **Do not presume to know how complex a system would be to upgrade merely by using it.**  You sit in a position of absolute privilege in that you do not have to think about any of the complexities or intricacies of how a change on form A will impact users on feature set B.  It is highly irresponsible and even downright *offensive* to suggest that this could be done by interns, as if the developers of Stack Overflow don't already have enough to deal with.

Comment: Check our Google's mission statement in the OP comment thread - no one doubts they're after money,  but the statement helps clarify their intentions and path to  gain money.

Comment: @Makoto: it's a fair point. The interns at our office are supervised, and we simply don't allow them to mail a shoddy job to our customers.

Comment: I have **really** never understood the thing where people assume that the developers working on the premiere programming site in the world are incompetent at programming.

Comment: @Makoto You really think *literally editing the description of tags, help pages, or other already existing text only resources* is so complex that SE can't be bothered to update them?  you *might* just be able to argue that for flag increases (ui size increases, new metric to track, etc) but I still am not convinced that these kinds of changes are expensive enough to out right *ignore* the curators of SO.  If something as simple as a line of text on the help page is that complicated to edit *then there is something fundamentally wrong with the way SE manages their site*.

Comment: @opa:  We in the community can handle tag edits, so staff don't need to get involved there.  Help pages are largely uniform across the network so a change in one may require changes in them all.  The same is true for flags with some limitations in the ability for communities to add custom flags for their needs, and **there _is_ a limit** to the amount of custom reasons that can be active for flags.

Comment: @opa:  You underestimate the complexity of the site.  From your perspective these seem simple; from the company's perspective, they aren't and they have been enumerated on before on Meta and Meta Stack Exchange.  A last point - **their priorities aren't your priorities**, and it'd be worth understanding and respecting that before believing that they're somehow incompetent because they didn't address your wish list.

Comment: @Makoto You've advocated personally that we should *keep shouting*. Yet you give this company the benefit of the doubt at every chance you get.  If you want to believe that they have literally no choice because of their priorities but to ignore the entire community, then fine, but you spreading around stockholm syndrome isn't going to help change things.  The fact remains that regardless of how difficult these changes are, they've got the capability to implement them, and even if they came in at a pace 10X slower than before it would still be infinitely better than what we're getting now.

Comment: "I think the reason folks in the Meta community get so upset is that they fail to appreciate or understand the interests of Stack Overflow the company." - I very much disagree.  We know exactly what SE is doing.  We're just looking longer term.  Focusing primarily on growth means the very reason for their success, the experts, evaporates, and once critical mass is lost, the company is going to circle the drain.  I understand just fine the company has to make money.  I just disagree that all this new user pandering will help sustain that success.

Comment: @opa:  Keep shouting about what is most important to you for this site to be sustainable and maintainable for decades to come.  This way, the PMs can hear you.  But that doesn't mean you get the privilege of slagging off their efforts when you don't feel like they're moving as fast as you want them to on the things you want them to move on.

Comment: @opa your responses only serve to underscore my point about Meta not understanding/appreciating how a business is run from a decision-making perspective. They are not ignoring the community; at worst they are not acquiescing to the requests (or demands, really) of a small subset of the site. They're banking on that vocal group being a minority and on enough SMEs being OK with how the site is maintained/company is run to stick around.

Comment: @opa keep in mind they don't *need* the expert-level contributors so much anymore as **the site has reached critical mass**, more or less, and there are almost no new really great questions asked anymore compared to the days of yesteryear. It's not critical that people as skilled/knowledgeable as Jon Skeet, Eric Lippert, Hans Passant, etc. stick around and keep answering... the kinds of questions most people ask today can be answered by people with only a few months to a few years of experience in that language/technology. These folks typically aren't as demanding/nostalgic for "Old SO".

Comment: @fbueckert And I'd bet you $100 that Stack Overflow has performed *many* cost-benefit analyses and studied growth projections to help determine its course(s) of action. These business decisions are made intentionally and are informed. Also keep in mind that the board of directors and executives consist of people who aren't Stack Overflow true believers or OG users... many may not have an account at all! It's of course fine to disagree with their course of action or think it's wrong; no business' leaders/management ever agree 100% on something, but it's the decision of the board/CEO that count.

Comment: I would also argue that most of the veteran users aren't sitting around arguing for major fundamental improvements the platform and upset at a lack of new features.  Yes, it's frankly embarrassing when the site can't so much as fix labels or descriptions that are just flat out wrong. A trivial amount of dev time, on minor fixes would have great return on investment. But that's not the biggest cause of friction. The biggest problem (recently) is SE's implementation of changes that actively hurts the quality of content. I'd be happier if they just did what they did in years past and did nothing.

Comment: I'm well aware of the focus is.  I think they're gambling on the goodwill built up over years sustaining the site over the years, and gambling **hard**.  That goodwill is not infinite, and at some point, they're going to run into the fact that a site built on user participation means those users also have a rather major voice.  I bet a general curator strike might actually have an impact to make that voice known a bit more bluntly than the formless grumbling we're all currently engaged in.

Comment: @fbueckert Strikes, by their nature, generally need to be able to be successful in the short term.  SO is designed to be an archive of information.  For it to really hurt the bottom line it's archive needs to cover a notably smaller percentage of programming questions people have.  That'd take a long time.  It will happen eventually if new good content stops being posted (or greatly slows down) but will require new important topics SO doesn't currently cover, and that people are seeking answers on, before the company's bottom line really suffers.

Comment: @Servy That part is going to happen organically as it is.  The point I'm making is that enough people stop actively curating, the uptick in crap that survives will just hasten that end.  You can't both give users agency to curate quality content, and then tell them they're doing it wrong after several years.

Comment: @fbueckert Sure, if SO continues to not address the problems they have, or, as they're currently doing, exacerbate them, then people will leave, fewer good reference material will be posted, and people will start looking elsewhere for that information.  It'll take a long time for the existing knowledge base to age to the point of it not attracting lots of traffic though.  But my main point was that you couldn't really organize an official strike that would include enough people and last long enough for SO to really notice.  It's too big, and it would take too long to make an impact.

Comment: @Servy That is a good point.  I guess it's a bit naive to assume that a short uptick in crap would make SE listen to those it needs to survive.  I appreciate the effort that Tim, Shog, and Catija put in to make it more transparent, but I feel most of it equates to PR spin than actual constructive change.  It might be time to just pack it in and let the horde of clueless new users try to keep things going.

Comment: @fbueckert As others have said, a big factor here is a lack of competition in the realm of "programming Q/A sites attempting to hold a high standard of quality for questions and answers".  Too many people are here just because the competitors aren't even *pretending* to have a focus on quality and to claim that low quality questions aren't welcome.

Comment: @TylerH Pushing out the experts and leaving the site to just coast on the content it already has will be great in the short term.  Sure, it'll take a good while, years most likely, for the content on the site to age to the point where it's not at least *one* of the primary resources for programmers looking for answers, but if you start looking 3-5 years or more out, then yeah, they need experts here answering questions.  Content goes out of date, new fields come up, etc.  That veteran users are taking a longer term view doesn't mean they don't understand the business.

Comment: Nice, so my comment using this answer as an analogy for domestic abuse was deleted. I guess it must've offended somebody... about the time censorship starts to creep in, is when you know that it's curtains for a site with a community.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it's possible to talk about what the goals of Stack Overflow (the company) are without understanding a few key principles.

- Stack Overflow (the site) is the ***largest*** site on the network, and most of its daily traffic statistics dwarf even the most recent network competitor.  For better and for worse, it is *the* snowflake.
- Stack Overflow (the company) until relatively recently, relied on a few sources of income - largely [VC funding](https://venturebeat.com/2015/01/20/stack-exchange-funding/) and ad revenue.
- Stack Overflow (the company) needs to figure out a way to maintain and sustain profitability since they explicitly deemphasize ads as a way to generate revenue, so we have paid and provided services, like (at one point in time) licensed versions of the service, Careers and now Teams.
- Stack Overflow (the company) has had some *mixed* to pessimistic reception from some of their endeavors, so it makes sense that they're a bit gun shy in talking to their most ardent and vocal community.

I would say that a lot of warm and fuzzies were lost with [some backlash to Stack Overflow Mobile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349255/1079354). 
 We [already *had* a mobile app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190200/175248) which had been in beta for years prior with what seemed to be few actual improvements to it, and there was a bit of a disconnect there.  The power users felt ignored and the people actually building it felt like they had wasted their time.

Then the responsive design for the network came along (finally!) and put the kibosh on any point to a mobile app.

The big thing here is that Stack Overflow, like any company, needs to find a sustainable revenue model for it to work, and side projects which don't contribute to the revenue model (like the mobile app and Documentation) can find themselves very quickly on the cutting board.

What's worse is the signal that *we* send - and I say "we" in the sense that we here on Meta are by far the best pool of users and the worst pool of users to get feedback from.  The signal for *years* was that mobile users wanted mobile chat, but they didn't get it because there is no evidence that this feature is prominent enough to implement the API and interface for.  This kind of has a trickle-down effect on a lot of feature announcements and a lot of new services which the team wants to solicit feedback; we fuss at them, sometimes constructive, sometimes unconstructive, and at some point it becomes impossible to discern the signal from the noise, and we become "grumpy" or "insatiable".

This is also where the disconnect becomes apparent.  The blog you linked to was actually really nice and I enjoyed it, but it highlights another shift in policy and direction.  **Developers don't post here as much as they used to.**  It's driven by actual project managers, and project managers don't *really* concern themselves with what the priorities of power users are, which leads to a significant disconnect.  If we don't feel like we're being heard, we're going to keep perpetuating a negative feedback loop and the situation isn't likely going to improve.

I should stress that I don't have a problem with PMs taking over for driving and delivering on deadlines.  Developers should be shielded from their customers to a degree, since it distracts from development time and effort.  A PM *must* be responsible for gathering this information and actually putting it in a form that a developer can digest and iterate on.

...I don't want to leave you walking away empty-handed here so I'll leave you with something simple.

## Focus on making this site a resource for engineers for years to come.

The company will need to figure out a way to keep the lights on, and for all intents and purposes, I hope they do.  Being bitter and resentful over how they're treating their veterans doesn't help us.  If they ultimately don't decide to work with us in whatever way they see fit, then that's fine...and the site will collapse for it.

But that isn't for us to actually worry about.

Comment: I like your statement - maybe replace "a" by "the best"

Comment: @kabanus:  Don't get me wrong; Stack Overflow is good but it can't beat well-written documentation.

Comment: But most documentation does not ask you "Did you read the documentation?"

Comment: @usr2564301:  ...which is why well-written documentation is better than SO, since you don't have that condensation attached to it while you're reading.

Comment: I think a manual would beat SO for specialized stuff like learning a new language or looking for a specific nuance. Hard to beat SO's breadth in both languages and small algorithms, not to mention common mistakes.

Comment: @Makoto Did you mean condescension perhaps? I hope I always stay dry when reading documentation and SO alike...

Comment: @TylerH:  Yeah, let's go with that. :)

Comment: @Makoto [Con-den-sa-tion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQGW46B6x_4) :)