# How to deal with an edit that removes the question sentence from question?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, flags

Sometimes I come across questions without a question or even a "?" inside the question text or title. (I used the search but could not find a similar question)

Normally I suggest to formulate a question and flag it for unclear what you're asking. Is that ok?

Today I looked at the edit history of [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276054/multiple-buttons-in-one-button) and someone actually removed the question sentence. I find that highly disturbing. Is rolling back that edit the correct way to deal with the issue?

Comment: “Could anyone please direct me to the right way?” doesn’t add anything to the question. You’re on a site which is all about directing people to the right way by providing a repository of knowledge, so why would this particular question need this sentence?

Comment: To scope the question. It could also be "Can you please implement this for me?", or "How can I do the expanding list?" which has a totally different meaning. Let me get this straight, I dont disagree that the question there has next to no meaning, but without any question the post is not just a bad question but unanswerable, in my view.

Comment: What information this sentence provides that could cripple the question?

Comment: @Xufox My usual process for answering is searching for the question. If I dont find a question I will not try to answer the "post", because most likely I will not be able to address the problem properly.

Comment: The question is a fine example of a "gimme teh codez" garbage, with our without that one sentence. It shouldn't have been edited not because the edit removed important information but because you don't polish turds, as you end up with turdy hands.

Comment: I would assume that the only reason you saw this at all was because this garbage got re-activated again.  Horrible, isn't it?  Big honking problem at SO, it is the garbage that gets most of the views because of these useless edits.  The good stuff quickly disappears from the front page.  This hyper-editor re-activates a lot of it all by himself and never fixes anything, if you see his name on the post then a DV is almost always the correct course of action.

Comment: [1/2] @HansPassant it's untrue about "_never fixes anything_". It's more about how we'd wish those so-called "_garbage_" posts to be handled. Wikipedia has the "[minor edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Minor_edit)" feature that allows to filter such edits from the recent activity page. Stack Exchange doesn't have this feature. Wikipedia has the "[bot edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bots)" feature that allows to filter such edits from the recent activity page. Stack Exchange doesn't allow bot edits, which also means we can't automate the edits at a slow fixed pace.

Comment: [2/2] And fundamentally, there is a goal conflict between those agreeing that ["_Stack Overflow is designed to be a high-quality repository of programming questions and answers._"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26017/263422) and those who seek to give/receive quick help within the first minutes of a question (and get bothered by old posts). See also the paragraph "[Okay, where does the Meta tension come from?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377519/1033581)". I wish we could roomba more, or vote more frequently.

Comment: @Cœur - editing is a legitimate activity at SO, but what you are doing is not.  You are averaging 100 edits per day, of course you never fix anything at that rate.  Everything at SO is rate limited but editing is not.  If you can't set a realistic goal for yourself, say 20/day, then you need to stop it completely, find something better to do with your free time.

Comment: @Cœur How is going around to questions that are extremely low quality, about to be deleted, and not having anything of value to save, and making some trivial grammatical change that leaves the question in just as useless of a state as it was in before, helping SO's goal of creating a high quality repository of knowledge?  Edits to old posts that *are actually of value*, and that  *make substantive improvements to those posts* don't have the problems Hans has raised.  Anyone that doesn't want to see *any* edits can simply look at newest, rather than active, questions.

Answer (score 8):

There won't be a universal answer as it depends greatly on the question itself.

An actual sentence with question mark isn't required so long as the question being asked is clear.  What really matters is the value that the removed content provides.

- Is the removed "question statement" unnecessary fluff or included simply to include a question mark? - If so, then it is probably unnecessary and the edit to remove it is fine
- Does the removed "question statement" contain information necessary to answer the question? - If so, then roll back the edit
- Is the question completely clear with or without the statement - if not, then you should be looking to vote to close and not worry about the edit.
- Is the question on-topic for the site and not too broad? - if not, then you should be looking to vote to close and not worry about the edit.

For the last 2 bullets, it doesn't matter whether the edit makes the question unclear.  The question needs to be closed, so just close it.  In fact, if you are reviewing a suggested edit, you should also reject the edit.  No sense reactivating a garbage question with a meaningless edit that will not fix the question.

In this case, the question is too broad with or without the statement.  The proper course of action is not roll back, leave it as-is and vote/flag to close the question.

Comment: The thing is that, for me, with the question it is too broad, without it it is unclear what you are asking. I dont actually know if that changes the closure process.

Comment: @leonardkraemer no, if the question is close worthy with the statement, then it is close worthy without the statement.  Just close it

Answer (score 3):

The question is clearly off-topic. But for the sake of your question, let's ignore this fact.

Without the sentence

> “Could anyone please direct me to the right way?”

You can't really know where OP is stuck, and what he really needs. It could be interpreted as follow:

> I want to create an Android app which has a bottom navigation menu. On
>   the navigation menu I want to add a lot of buttons so what I want is
>   to add a 'More' button, which when clicked will expand a list of
>   buttons.
>
> **How do I expand the list of buttons? [My addition]**

I don't see any reason how removing the only question in the post improves it.

Again, the question is definitely off-topic and should be closed, my answer should hold for more generic cases.